# Changing image src with jQuery in CodeIgniter platform

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, image-replacement

I'm having a bit of trouble changing the image source, using jQuery, in my CodeIgniter website.

I'm building a custom onclick() function attached to my images (i have a list of 'checkbox' images inside a  list, and when clicked I want to replace it with the 'checked' image), but when I try to alert out the src of that image all I get is 'undefined'. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML code:

```
<img src="<?php echo imagePath(); ?>icons/checkbox_empty.png" class="checkbox1" onclick="checkbox(1)" /> html text here...

<img src="<?php echo imagePath(); ?>icons/checkbox_empty.png" class="checkbox2" onclick="checkbox(2)" /> html text here...
and so on...
```

jQuery code:

```
function checkbox(number){
var image = $('#checkbox'+number).attr("src");
alert(image);
}
```

Once again, any help really would be appreciated. Tim.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but what about `onclick="checkbox(this)"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the class selector, not the id selector:
`.checkbox1` not `#checkbox1`

Give that a shot.

Comment: OMG... thanks a million Tim... I feel like such an idiot, how I missed that I don't know!!! lol. Sorry that I cannot 'upvote' your reply, I'm a new member and it wont let me... also, am I meant to mark this as 'answered' somehow?